# Cannot find module @restart/context/forwardRef during npm build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install, react-bootstrap

I recently started having a problem with `npm build` after upgrading to newer version of `react-bootstrap` (`1.0.0-beta.6`).

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Cannot find module: '@restart/context/forwardRef'. Make sure this package is installed.
./node_modules/react-bootstrap/es/ThemeProvider.js

You can install this package by running: yarn add @restart/context/forwardRef.
```

I tried running the provided `yarn` command but this is not a valid package name. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this without going back to the old version (which does not support tabs, which is something I am using)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an upstream issue with [@restart/context](https://github.com/react-restart/context/), which just released a version that breaks importing `forwardRef` like this:

```js
import forwardRef from '@restart/context/forwardRef'
```

Quick fix is to downgrade to 2.1.2 by running `yarn add @restart/context@2.1.2`.

Longer term fix is to wait for `react-bootstrap` to either fix their imports or lock their `package.json` to this version of `@restart/context`.

Edit: I added an issue to the `react-bootstrap` repo to track progress here: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3576