# React App failed to compile - Module not found: Can't resolve 'react'

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

I'm using `create-react-app` with `react-bootstrap` and I'm getting this error when I run npm start:

> Failed to compile ../node_modules/@restart/context/forwardRef.js
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'react' in 'C:\Users...\node_modules@restart\context'

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

I already tried deleting `package-lock.json` and running npm install again but it didn't help.

Comment: Check if "react" package exists in ./node_modules folder. 
Also delete node_modules completely. node_modules will get generated again. Hope this helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55419787/cannot-find-module-restart-context-forwardref-during-npm-build)

Comment: Maybe you need to do an `npm install`?

Comment: Remove `node_modules`, run `npm cache clean` and run `npm install` again.

Answer (score 1):

I got some error. I try to use the below step; It is running eventually.

```
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
```

Then I deleted **node_modules**, after that, I run the below code

```
npm install --force
```